# How can I find extended ASCII characters in a file using Perl?

Tags: perl, parsing, encoding, extended-ascii

How can I find extended ASCII characters in a file using Perl? Can anyone get the script?

.....thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the extended [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters have value [128 and higher](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can just call [ord](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) on individual characters and handle those with a value >= 128. The following code reads from stdin and prints only the extended ASCII characters:

```
while (<>) {
  while (/(.)/g) {
    print($1) if (ord($1) >= 128);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) together with [chr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) will also work. Example:

```
while (<>) {
  foreach (unpack("C*", $_)) {
    print(chr($_)) if ($_ >= 128);
  }
}
```

(I'm sure some Perl guru can condense both of these to two one-liners...)

---

To print the line numbers instead, you can use the following (this does not remove duplicates, and will have odd behaviour when unicode is passed):

```
while (<>) {
  while (/(.)/g) {
    print($. . "\n") if (ord($1) >= 128);
  }
}
```

(Thanks [Yaakov Belch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104746/yaakov-belch) for the `$.` tip.)

Comment: It is very slow and ineffective approach, see Dave Sherohman's solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881931/how-to-print-numbers-of-line-containing-extended-ascii-characters-in-perl/882113#882113 It is far faster and simpler.

Comment: This answer was posted before Dave's. I have seen Dave's approach, and it is to be preferred in most instances. This just shows that I'm a Perl novice. I choose not to delete this answer because the last part appears to do exactly what the questioner wants. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882122/reading-a-file-char-by-char-and-checking-for-extented-ascii-char

Comment: ...ah, that page has been deleted. Suffice it to say, the question stated that the line number should be printed for *each* extended ASCII character. This is what my solution does.

Answer (score 8):

The first printable ASCII character is `space` (32).  The last printable ASCII character is `~` (126).  So I'd probably use

```
while (<>) {
  print "$.\n" if /[^ -~]/;
}
```

although it will, admittedly, also display lines containing control characters as well as extended ASCII.

**Edit:** Changed to print the line number rather than the line itself.

Comment: It's easy to print the line number instead of the line:

while(<>) { print "$.\n" if /[^ -~]/;}

This should solve the stated problem

Comment: Whoops!  I was just reading the question itself and missed that the title specified that he wanted the line number.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 5):

Oneliner:

```
perl -nE'say$.if/[\xE0-\xFF]/'
```

for older perl versions

```
perl -lne'print$.if/[\xE0-\xFF]/'
```

Answer (score 2):

A crucial question is whether the

use bytes;

pragma should be in effect. The poster should decide that. For picking *characters* with codes greater than 127, the following will suffice:

```
print grep 127 < ord, split // while <>;
```

or

```
print grep /[^[:ascii:]]/, split // while <>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil's answer:

```
perl -nE'say$.if/[\xE0-\xFF]/'
```

only tests a limited part of the non-printing should presumably be

```
perl -nE'say$.if/[\x80-\xFF]/'
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

What about grep?

```
grep [\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]+ *
```