# search document for non-ascii

Tags: regex, perl, ascii, character

An application on my computer needs to read in a text file. I have several, and one doesn't work; the program fails to read it and tells me that there is a bad character in it somewhere. My first guess is that there's a non-ascii character in there somewhere, but I have no idea how to find it. Perl or any generic regex would be nice. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I believe you can find an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881931/how-can-i-find-extended-ascii-characters-in-a-file-using-perl)?

Comment: I accepted mathematical coffee's because it was supereasy- worked in Notepad++

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `[^\x20-\x7E]` to match a non-ASCII character.

e.g. `grep -P '[^\x20-\x7E]' suspicious_file`

Comment: I had a problem using this, as it would also identify all of end of line characters in my file.  Combining your answer with Ruakh's though worked like a charm:
[^\t\n\r\x20-\x7E]

Comment: In my case, the [answer from the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/882437/873282) was better: `[\xE0-\xFF]`

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -wne 'printf "byte %02X in line $.\n", ord $& while s/[^\t\n\x20-\x7E]//;'
```

will find every character that is not an ASCII glyphic character, tab, space, or newline.

If it reports `0D`s (carriage-returns) in files that are O.K., then change `\t\n` to `\t\n\r`.

If it only reports `0D`s in files that are bad, then you can probably fix those files by running `dos2unix` on them.

Comment: Just an addendum, one should run the input as the final non-listed argument.

Comment: Like that, thank you! I had to change it slightly for a DOS console:
`perl -wne "printf qq(byte %02X in line $.\n), ord $& while s/[^\t\n\x20-\x7E]//;" <test.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If you use tabulators in your source code as well, try this pattern:

```
[^\x08-\x7E]
```

Works also in Notepad++