# Find non-ASCII characters in a text file and convert them to their Unicode equivalent

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

I am importing .txt file from a remote server and saving it to a database. I use a .Net script for this purpose. I sometimes notice a garbled word/characters (`Ullerهkersvنgen`) inside the files, which makes a problem while saving to the database.

I want to filter all such characters and convert them to unicode before saving to the database.

Note: I have been through many similar posts but had no luck.

Your help in this context will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your script does know the correct encoding of your text snippet than that should be the regular expression to find all Non-ASCII charactres:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20890052/1144966 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8845398/1144966

Also, the base-R tools package provides two functions to detect non-ASCII characters:

```
tools::showNonASCII()
tools::showNonASCIIfile()
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to know or at least guess the character encoding of the data in order to be able to convert it properly. So you should try and find information about the origin and format of the text file and make sure that you read the file properly in your software.

For example, “Ullerهkersvنgen” looks like a Scandinavian name, with Scandinavian letters in it, misinterpreted according to a wrong character encoding assumption or as munged by an incorrect character code conversion. The first Arabic letter in it, “ه”, is [U+064](http://www.eki.ee/letter/chardata.cgi?ucode=0647)7 ARABIC LETTER HEH. In the ISO-8859-6 encoding, it is E7 (hex.); in windows-1256, it is E5. Since Scandinavian text are normally represented in ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 (when Unicode encodings are not used), it is natural to check what E7 and E5 mean in them: “ç” and “å”. For linguistic reasons, the latter is much more probable here. The second Arabic letter is “ن” U+0646 ARABIC LETTER NOON, which is E4 in windows-1256. And in ISO-8859-1, E4 is “ä”. This makes perfect sense: the word is “Ulleråkersvägen”, a real Swedish street name (in Uppsala, at least).

Thus, the data is probably ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 (Windows Latin 1) encoded text, incorrectly interpreted as windows-1256 (Windows Arabic). No conversion is needed; you just need to *read* the data as windows-1252 encoded. (After reading, it can of course be converted to another encoding.)

Comment: Yes you are correct 100%. “Ullerهkersvنgen” is equal “Ulleråkersvägen”. Now how can we do this through ASP.Net to automatically detect such characters and convert them accordingly.

Comment: @Mehboob, you cannot. On some cases, some heuristics might be applied, but the general issue of deducing character encoding from the data alone requires human intellect and understanding plus some experience (and might be impossible).

Comment: Can't we use a regular expression to catch all non-ASCII characters and then convert them to unicode?

Comment: Yes you can if you know the encoding. As such, the data is just bits. What would you convert 01100010 to if you did not know what character it is supposed to denote?

Comment: Can you give me a code example? apply the encoding you just explained in your answer and thats OK as I have already said.